# Linux Device Driver, kernel thread can't open file?

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a Linux Driver with Linux Kernel Modules when, user can write and when user calls close, driver has to flush content into a file in another directory with same name of the device file.

I have this problem: when a process calls close, the driver can open a file and flush all its content correctly; when the process is killed (for example, from the terminal with a `kill`), device driver fails to execute `filp_open` becuse `fs->CURRENT` is set to NULL. So, I was trying to start a kernel thread to do this work.

When I try opening a file in the same directory, for example `filp_open("myfile"...)`, it works correctly. But if I have to open a file in another directory, so `filp_open("dirA/myfile")`, `filp_open` returns -2. But this not going to happen when I call `filp_open` from the main thread.

This is my code:

```
static int thread_fn(void *unused){
  struct thread_data* td = (struct thread_data *) unused;
  if(td == NULL)
     printk(KERN_INFO "td is null\n");
  struct file* filp=filp_open("/dirA/myfile",O_RDWR,0666);
  if(filp == NULL || (IS_ERR(filp)))
    printk(KERN_INFO "filp is null!\n");
  else
    printk(KERN_INFO "filp is not null!\n");

  size_t filp_size = filp->f_inode->i_size;
  printk(KERN_INFO "size on release: %ld\n",filp_size);
  if(filp_size > td->size){
    printk(KERN_INFO "truncating file\n");
    truncate_setsize(filp->f_inode, td->size);
  }


  inode_lock(filp->f_inode); 
  //file_write(filp,/*file->f_pos*/0,td->data,td->size);
  inode_unlock(filp->f_inode);

  printk(KERN_INFO "Thread Stopping\n");
  do_exit(0);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my `device_release` function:

```
static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
   if(my_data->buffer == NULL)
      return -ENOMEM;

  struct thread_data* td=alloc_mem(sizeof(struct thread_data));
  td->filename=my_data->filename;
  td->data=my_data->buffer;
  td->size=my_data->size;

  thread_st = kthread_run(thread_fn, (void *)td,"Thread!");
  if (thread_st)
    printk(KERN_INFO "Thread Created successfully\n");
  else
    printk(KERN_ERR "Thread creation failed\n");

  return 0;
}
```

What's the problem? I can't understand, it could be an OS problem? I have also tried with `set_fs`/`get_fs` but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I have an update: if I put flag O_CREAT, filp_open doesn't return error, but file isn't created; so, kernel thread cannot operate on file?

Comment: This does not answer the question. To add more information to the question, click the "edit" button below the question.